# browser not recognizing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, console

so here is the deal.. I was trying to make the famous cows and bulls game using JavaScript and every thing was working fine while I was testing it on the console without the code where I make `$outputDiv` variables but as I tried to append div tags inside the body using JQuery the browser won't recognize them. Take a look at the code:

**HTML:**

```html
<body id="body">
    <input type="text" name="inputBox" id="inputBox" />
    <button onclick="game();">press me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
function game() {
    var words = Array(["make", "lake", "take"], ["food", "rude"], ["tall", "ball"], ["cows", "bulls"]);` 


    var chosenWord = decideWord(words);

    var chosenWord = chosenWord.toLowerCase();
    var userInput = $('#inputBox').val();

    guesses(chosenWord, userInput);

}

function decideWord(words) {

    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * words[i].length);
    var word = words[i][j];
    var word = filter(word, words);

    return word;
}

function guesses(chosenWord, userInput) {
    var bull = 0;
    var cow = 0;
    var autoletters = chosenWord.split("");
    var inputletters = userInput.split("");

    for (var count = 0; count < userInput.length; count++) {
        if (chosenWord.search(inputletters[count]) != -1) {
            if (autoletters[count] == inputletters[count]) {
                bull++;
            } else {
                cow++;
            }
        }

    }
    // $('#body').append($outputDiv1);
    //  $('#od1').text("BULLS:"+bull+"COWS:"+cows);
    console.log("BULLS:" + bull + "COWS:" + cow);

}

function filter(Word, words) {
    var autoletters = Word.split("");

    if (autoletters[0] == autoletters[1] || autoletters[0] == autoletters[2] || autoletters[0] == autoletters[3] || autoletters[1] == autoletters[2] || autoletters[1] == autoletters[3] || autoletters[2] == autoletters[3]) {
        var Word = decideWord(words);
        return Word;
    } else {
        return Word;
    }

}

function makeDivs() {
    var $outputDiv1 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od1" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv2 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od2" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv3 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od3" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv4 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od4" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv5 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od5" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv6 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od6" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv7 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od7" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv8 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od8" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv9 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od9" ></div>');
    var $outputDiv10 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od10" ></div>');
    var outputDivTags = Array($outputDiv1, $outputDiv2, $outputDiv3, $outputDiv4, $outputDiv5, $outputDiv6, $outputDiv7, $outputDiv8, $outputDiv9, $outputDiv10);
    return outputDivTags;
}
```

**Console:**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     //on startup
Uncaught ReferenceError: game is not defined //on pressing the button
```

Comment: @mplungjan AFAIK you should not request somebody to accept answers. But you should let him know how it works, as you also did :)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a matter of [syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax): You can *never* write HTML *or any other language* inside of your JavaScript except as a string. And strings are *always* written in quotes.

So these lines

```js
var $outputDiv1 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od1" ></div>);
var $outputDiv2 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od2" ></div>);
var $outputDiv3 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od3" ></div>);
var $outputDiv4 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od4" ></div>);
var $outputDiv5 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od5" ></div>);
var $outputDiv6 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od6" ></div>);
var $outputDiv7 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od7" ></div>);
var $outputDiv8 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od8" ></div>);
var $outputDiv9 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od9" ></div>);
var $outputDiv10 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od10" ></div>);
```

Should look like this:

```js
var $outputDiv1 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od1" ></div>');
var $outputDiv2 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od2" ></div>');
var $outputDiv3 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od3" ></div>');
var $outputDiv4 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od4" ></div>');
var $outputDiv5 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od5" ></div>');
var $outputDiv6 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od6" ></div>');
var $outputDiv7 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od7" ></div>');
var $outputDiv8 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od8" ></div>');
var $outputDiv9 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od9" ></div>');
var $outputDiv10 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od10" ></div>');
```

Note the `'` (single quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first  of all, try adding quotes around

```
var $outputDiv1 = $(<div class="outputDiv" id ="od1" ></div>);
```

So, like:

```
var $outputDiv1 = $('<div class="outputDiv" id ="od1" ></div>');
```

That should help a bit.

That goes for all those lines.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (although you do not actually USE the function in the posted code)

```
function makeDivs() {
  var outputDivTags=[];
  for (var i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    outputDivTags.push($('<div/>',{"class":"outputDiv", "id":"od"+i}));
  }
  return outputDivTags;
}
```

Comment: Dude you still have quotation issues xD